# Add multiple window.onload events

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, listener

In my ASP.NET User Control I'm adding some JavaScript to the `window.onload` event:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), onloadScriptName))
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), onloadScriptName, 
    "window.onload = function() {myFunction();};", true);
```

My problem is, if there is already something in the `onload` event, than this overwrites it. How would I go about allowing two user controls to each execute JavaScript in the `onload` event?

**Edit:** Thanks for the info on third party libraries. I'll keep them in mind.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which provides a framework for cleaning adding multiple event handlers?

Comment: wee dont need no stinkin libraries!
fyi, for firefox, its window.attachEvent('load', myFunction); not window.attachEvent('ONload', myFunction);

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Most of the "solutions" suggested are Microsoft-specific, or require bloated libraries. Here's one good way. This works with W3C-compliant browsers and with Microsoft IE.

```
if (window.addEventListener) // W3C standard
{
  window.addEventListener('load', myFunction, false); // NB **not** 'onload'
} 
else if (window.attachEvent) // Microsoft
{
  window.attachEvent('onload', myFunction);
}
```

Comment: Note: function assigned(myFunction) in window.attachEvent('onload', myFunction); is always fired after any function assigned to window.onload

Comment: excuse me sir, what does NB **not** 'onload'  means?

Comment: @meJustAndrew he means that when you use addEventListener you don't use 'onload' you just use 'load'.

Answer (score 20):

There still is an ugly solution (which is far inferior to using a framework or `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`) that is to save the current `onload` event:

```
function addOnLoad(fn)
{ 
   var old = window.onload;
   window.onload = function()
   {
       old();
       fn();
   };
}

addOnLoad(function()
{
   // your code here
});
addOnLoad(function()
{
   // your code here
});
addOnLoad(function()
{
   // your code here
});
```

Note that frameworks like jQuery will provide a way to execute code when the DOM is ready and not when the page loads.

DOM being ready means that your HTML has loaded but not external components like images or stylesheets, allowing you to be called long before the load event fires.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem today so I solved it having an `index.js` with the following:

```
window.onloadFuncs = [];

window.onload = function()
{
 for(var i in this.onloadFuncs)
 {
  this.onloadFuncs[i]();
 }
}
```

and in additional js files that i want to attach the onload event I just have to do this:

```
window.onloadFuncs.push(function(){
 // code here
});
```

I normally use jQuery though, but this time I was restricted to pure js wich forced to use my mind for a while!

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution. Just have to remember to include the index/loader script first in the HTML header.

Answer (score 3):

[Mootools](http://mootools.net/) is another great JavaScript framework which is fairly easy to use, and like RedWolves said with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can can just keep chucking as many handlers as you want.

For every *.js file I include I just wrap the code in a function.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    alert('Just put all your code here');
});
```

And there are also [advantages of using domready instead of onload](http://walkthrough.ifupdown.com/walkthrough-1.2/domready.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.attachEvent("onload", myOtherFunctionToCall);

function myOtherFunctionToCall() {
    // do something
}
```

edit:  hey, I was just getting ready to log in with Firefox and reformat this myself!  Still doesn't seem to format code for me with IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about ASP.NET, but why not write a custom function for the onload event that in turn calls both functions for you?  If you've got two functions, call them both from a third script which you register for the event.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx), it looks like you *can* call this function multiple times to register multiple scripts.  You just need to use different keys (the second argument).

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), key1, function1, true);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), key2, function2, true);
```

I believe that should work.

Comment: Don't these scripts get executed when the page gets to them? Not during onload?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jquery

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // jQuery functions to initialize after the page has loaded.
});
```