# Can't get no javascript to execute on an ASP.NET user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, scriptmanager, clientscript

I'm trying to do the simplest thing, to show an alert popup through javascript from my code-behind of a user control (ascx.cs).

I've tried

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSave, GetType(), "uniqueID", "alert('hello');", true);
}
```

as well as

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "uniqueID", "alert('hello');", true);
```

but nothing seems to work for me. The control is located within an RadAjaxPanel (telerik) in an ASPX page.

I'm missing something obvious here. Any ideas what?

**EDIT:** The javascript is not injected into the html source as far as I can see. I look for the ID and the actual alert statement in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the problem was the Telerik RadAjaxPanel. I just had to set the EnableOutsideScripts to true on them, like so:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="ajaxpanel" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="ajaxLoadingPanel" EnableOutsideScripts="true">
```

And then I could use the following code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSave, GetType(), "uniqueID", "alert('hello');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass page's type to *client script type* parameter :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(MyPage), 
    "myPostBackScript", script, true);
```

**EDIT :** Normally this code works, but I don't know how telerik's control effects the injected script. I think you should open HTML source of the page and try to find injected script. This will help us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<form runat="server"` in your page?

Answer (score 0):

do you call if from onClienClick event of the button? whatever control you're using, make sure you're calling the js from a client-side event

also, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) for ideas

#### EDIT

you cannot CALL js from the server, js is CLIENT-SIDE script. what you can do is to Register your script AFTER you do all the checking, and tie it to onload event. see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434/how-do-i-add-an-additional-window-onload-event-in-javascript) for details

#### EDIT2

check out [the last post on this page](http://forums.asp.net/t/999492.aspx)

Comment: It's called from the server side button click event, since I have to do some server side checks before I throw up the alert box.