# my own $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, document-ready

I have the following problem: I've got a website that can't have dependencies to javascript-files. I want to have the same function as `$(document).ready()` in jquery. How would that look like? Thanks.

Comment: that's abit tough to do in javascript, but an easier alternative is to use `window.onload` but they are not the samething.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript:how to write $(document).ready like event without jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989095/javascripthow-to-write-document-ready-like-event-without-jquery) and [document.ready equivalent without jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onLoad` works, but it waits until all images and stuff are loaded.  If you just want it to run when the DOM is ready, you can do this (found [here](http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/07/27/javascript-windowonload-is-bad-mkay/)):

```
// Create onDomReady event
window.onDomReady = function(f){
    if(document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
    }
    // For IE
    else{
        document.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(document.readyState == "interactive"){
                f();
            }
        };
    }
};

// Attach a callback to onDomReady
window.onDomReady(function(){
    alert("The DOM is ready!");
});
```

Comment: +1: I am amazed why you agreed in the comment that both are equal?

Comment: @yetanothercoder: I did, because while not exactly the same, maybe it's good enough for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You could just look at the jQuery source code. If you want a simple "emulation", just include/call your JavasScript as the last element of `<body>`

```
   <!-- ... start of your HTML document -- -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
      likeDocumentReady();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before jQuery onLoad was a common practice, a much detailed answer in this link where you can check for cross browser solution.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're looking for the `onload` event. But yes123 is right, you should start accepting answers.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // yadda
}
```

Comment: @whoughton: In the blue box under the question with the asker's name.

Comment: @whoughton: Sure... April Fools!

Comment: @Bjorn:-1 Wrong information. jQuery DOM Ready is not same as javascript window.load() http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready() Is it really April fools?