# A good cross-browser "ready" event without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, onload

I need to create the equivalent of jQuery's `ready` event without using jQuery. It needs to work on as many browsers as possible and cannot mess up the `body.onload` handler (i.e. if there's already a handler set, the function shouldn't overwrite it). I checked jQuery's code but don't understand how it works because it uses many jQuery's functions.

Any suggestion on how to do that?

**Edit:** I have no control over where my code is going to be inserted that's why it needs to play as nicely as possible with the existing body.onload handler. It also means I cannot be sure the code will be inserted at the bottom of the page (most likely it won't be).

Comment: I recommend trying to understand how jQuerys works, or checking out another frameworks implementations such as mootools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript:how to write $(document).ready like event without jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989095/javascripthow-to-write-document-ready-like-event-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:
http://www.freelancephp.net/en/domready-javascript-object-cross-browser/

Non jquery implementation of DOM ready

Answer (score 3):

[Smallest cross browser DOMReady code, ever.](http://www.dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var ready = function (f) {
        (/in/.test(document.readyState)) ?
          setTimeout('r(' + f + ')', 9) :
          f();
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      ready(function () {
        alert('DOM Ready!');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply include your `<script>` tag at the very bottom. This way, it will only load after all the rest of the content had finished loading.

Comment: I believe it is. Does jQuery usually wait for images and such to finish loading completely?

Comment: @dotweb: It *might* - but I wouldn't rely on this, especially if `iframe`s are involved.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: jQuery's `ready` event fires before the DOM `load` event - so images don't have to be fully loaded yet.