# Create a function like jQuery(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How can I do that?

It seems that you can have multiple jQuery's ready() functions, and they will all run when the DOM is loaded.

So how can I create my own ready()-like function? :)

Comment: You could check out the source to see how they do it ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "ready()-like"?  What aspects of the jQuery facility do you want to mimic?

Comment: More on that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989095/javascripthow-to-write-document-ready-like-event-without-jquery

Comment: this may help http://www.dustindiaz.com/smallest-domready-ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function _addEvent(e, evt, handler){
    if(evt == "ready")
        evt = "DOMContentLoaded";

    if(typeof handler !== 'function')return;
    if (e.addEventListener)
        e.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
    else if (e.attachEvent)
        e.attachEvent("on" + evt, handler);
    else
    {
        var oldHandler = e["on" + evt];   
        function newHandler(event){
            handler.call(e, event);
            if(typeof oldhandler === 'function')oldhandler.call(e, event);
        }
    }
}
var _events = ["ready", "click", "mousedown"]; //...
var _myLib = function(item){
    function eventWorker(item, event){
        this.add = function(handler){
            _addEvent(item, event, handler);
        };
    }
    for(var i=0;i<_events.length;i++)
        this[_events[i]] = (new eventWorker(item, _events[i])).add;
};
var MyLib = function(item){
    return new _myLib(item);
};

MyLib(document).ready(function(){alert("I am ready!");});
```

Test =>
http://jsfiddle.net/vgraN/

Comment: Is that compiled coffeescript?

Comment: no, or i do not know, or i did not understand :) I wrote it myself just for answering

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to identify what it is you need the function for - is it to respond to a particular browser event?

jQuery's `$(document).ready(fn)` uses an array internally to hold the functions to execute when the DOM has loaded. Adding a new `ready(fn)` call appends the function `fn` to the array. When the DOM has loaded (which is detected in various ways according to which browser the code is executing within), each function in turn in the array is executed. Any functions added using `ready(fn)` after the DOM has loaded are executed immediately.

In summary, you can use an array to store the functions to execute whenever it is that you need to execute them.

Take a look at [**domready**](https://github.com/cms/domready/blob/master/domready.js), a standalone port of the `ready(fn)` function from jQuery to get some ideas about how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to make an array of functions and append new callbacks to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to do cross browser.

If you assume the DOMContentLoaded event exists then you can just make

```
var domready = (function () {
  var cbs = [];
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    cbs.forEach(function (f) {
      f();
    });
  });

  return function (cb) {
    cbs.push(cb);
  };
})();
```

You can use other fallbacks like `window.onload` and a hackish scroll check like jQuery does.

I'd recommend either using [domready](https://github.com/ded/domready/blob/master/src/ready.js) or reading the source.

Comment: If you have `addEventListener` you don't actually need an array, though, the browser will do it for you.

Comment: @minitech Meh it's more efficient to listen on the event once.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a function which when passed a function will call that function at a particular time?  (Also, it can be called multiple times.)  If so this is how I would do it it.  (Based on jQuery code.)

```
var funcQueue = (function () {
    var funcList = [];

    function runAll() {
      var len = funcList.length, 
          index = 0;

      for (; index < len; index++)
         funcList[index].call();  // you can pass in a "this" parameter here.

    }

    function add(inFunc) {
       funcList.push(inFunc);
    }

})();
```

To use:

```
   funcQueue.add(function () { alert("one"); });
   funcQueue.add(function () { alert("two"); });


   funcQueue.runAll();  // should alert twice.
```