# Javascript error - cannot call method 'appendChild' of null (svgicons)

Tags: javascript, svg

I get this error in the Chrome Developer Tools, but I can't see any errors visually on the page.

Here is a short extract of the JS:

```
function svgIcon( el, config, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this.svg = Snap( this.options.size.w, this.options.size.h );
        this.svg.attr( 'viewBox', '0 0 64 64' );
        this.el.appendChild( this.svg.node );
        // state
        this.toggled = false;
        // click event (if mobile use touchstart)
        this.clickevent = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
        // icons configuration
        this.config = config[ this.el.getAttribute( 'data-icon-name' ) ];
        // reverse?
        if( hasClass( this.el, 'si-icon-reverse' ) ) {
            this.reverse = true;
        }
        if( !this.config ) return;
        var self = this;
```

I believe that this code does not tell much, so the page can be found here: http://goo.gl/j7M5r8

I have tried solving the problem by looking into other similar cases on Stackoverflow, and it points out that there are either something missing or something with the order it is read/written in.

I have not written *svgicons.js*, so there are not supposed to be any issues with it. However I can see that some has the same issues as me, but there are not provideded an explanation or answer for the problem. [Here is basically the same question from another person.](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/05/animated-svg-icons-with-snap-svg/comment-page-3/#comment-465868)

Relevant files:

http://goo.gl/0RisGa

http://goo.gl/UgWHMS

http://goo.gl/X269NO

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946428/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-appendchild-of-null)

Comment: rather than going to a website, let me ask, how are you calling `svgIcon` function

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Are you meaning the invoking? Incase: `window.svgIcon = svgIcon;` From my minor knowledge about JS I am not sure if that's what you are refering to. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your hamburger_animations.js file - it's at http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/hamburger_animation.js

```
(function() {                           
    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.si-icons-default > .si-icon' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
        var svgicon = new svgIcon( el, svgIconConfig );
    } );
    new svgIcon( document.querySelector( '.si-icons-easing .si-icon-hamburger' ), svgIconConfig, { easing : mina.backin } );
    new svgIcon( document.querySelector( '.si-icons-easing .si-icon-hamburger-cross' ), svgIconConfig, { easing : mina.elastic, speed: 600              } );
    })();
```

`document.querySelector( '.si-icons-easing .si-icon-hamburger' )` is resulting in null

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I actually tried to delete that line right now if I could get any differents, but no, still error...

Comment: delete the next line as well, you have no element with class si-icon-easing so both of those querySelector lines will fail

Comment: Okay, thanks. Impressive how fast you can solve questions. Thank you, again :)