# Custom Js for single page in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a pure java script solution this; 
http://jsfiddle.net/IMAGINEUX/AQrNs/1/

I would like it to fire once the DOMready:

```
    $('#menu-item-156').mouseover(function(){
$(this).find('ul').slideDown();
```

});

$('#menu-item-156').trigger('mouseover');

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Simply prefix your jQuery selector with your page class assigned to the `body` element by Wordpress, something like:

```
$('.my-page #menu-item-156').mouseover(function(){
     $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
});

$('#menu-item-156').trigger('mouseover');
```

This will make sure that the Javascript fires only on the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

You could either prepend it with the single page class as @Sunyatasattva mentioned or you could enqueue that script only on the page you need to use it on.

**functions.php**

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'dropdown', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/dropdown.js', array( 'jquery' ), 1.0, true );

    if ( is_page( 156 ) ) :
        wp_enqueue_script( 'dropdown' );
    endif;

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: I have a plugin that allows me to insert <script> on page/post: I am mainly confused about how to DOMready + this function without jquery as it is not working via plugin. < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989095/javascripthow-to-write-document-ready-like-event-without-jquery>  Not sure what the best way to do this via WP?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });` Is there a reason why you are not able to use jQuery?

Comment: I think I may have confused the crux of the issue <http://jsfiddle.net/IMAGINEUX/AQrNs/>    This is the functionality I need: but I have no Idea how this would look in <head><script>" code " </script> </head>

Comment: It would look like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/AQrNs/3/. Looks like you have a few html syntax errors going on as well. The menu-item-156 id is missing an opening quote and looks like there is an extra </li> tag at the end.