# SSRS Reports browser compatibility issues

Tags: google-chrome, deployment, reporting-services, safari

I am using SSRS 2008 to deploy couple of reports to my server. Everything runs fine on IE. But Chrome and Safari does not display any reports. I can see the ‘Reports’ folder but when I click on the reports inside the folder, it displays nothing, whereas IE runs without any error. Talking about error, Firefox also display error on more complex reports…

I have gone through every solution on this forum
[SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports are blank in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome)
I tried appending function pageLoad() too but no success…
I am not sure I can use javascript anywhere because all I am doing is deploying the reports to my localhost/reportserver  and then I browse to localhost/reports to see if the reports are deployed.

Comment: Conducting a search on this shows this might be a related issue.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome

Comment: G00p3k... thanks for the comment, but as I mentioned in my post, I have already gone through that thread and tried its solution... but no success

Comment: My bad. I must have missed that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports in Safari/Chrome but works fine in Firefox/Internet Explorer 8... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reportviewer-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure JavaScript is enabled in the browser.

I still had some trouble so I installed IE tab for Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

Here is some additional information on non-IE SSRS browser support:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jay... your first solution did help ofcourse :)... however I am bummed after reading the second link...

Answer (score 0):

I placed the solution here:

[SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports in Safari/Chrome but works fine in Firefox/Internet Explorer 8... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in/18502489#18502489)

See the title named: CSS Based System Wide Solution