# ssrs 2012 ugly menu in internet explorer 11

Tags: reporting-services

the problem is as follow :

the report menu is not well displayed on internet explorer 11 (ie11). All the items are displayed as a stack/block when they should be inline

[image: in image...]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://thierry.schmit.free.fr/images/ssrs2012ie11.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution, as initiated by this [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome/7043409#7043409) is to edit "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11_00.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js"
by adding the following :

```
function pageLoad() {    
    var element = document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl09");
    if (element) {
        element.style.overflow = "visible"; 
    } 

    fixMenu();
}

function fixMenu() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        var c =  tables[i].attributes["class"];
        if ( typeof(c) != 'unefined' && c != null) {
            if ( c.nodeValue.indexOf("WidgetSetSpacer") != -1 || c.nodeValue.indexOf("WidgetShortSpacer") != -1) {
                tables[i].style.display = "";
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```