# The URL from web service of Report Service manager returns a blank page (no error specified)

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I really need your help.
I installed sql server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition and try to open the Web Service Url / Report manager URL but when it appears on the browser, it only gives me a blank page like this image below:

http://postimg.org/image/6mu71jrsl/

Nothing appears, not even an error. The title of the tab also doesn't change into Home- Report Manager.
It's very confusing since I installed them in default.
If there is an error, I still can troubleshoot it and resolve it. But now, I only get blank page with no error. Please...., can anyone help me? or has anyone resolved this same issue before? Thanks before!

Comment: First thing to do is compare this to IE; Chrome is known to be unsupported and have various issues with 2008R2... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/

Comment: I've already tried that on IE, but still the same problem. Nothing appears