# SSRS report (in asp.net Report Viewer) not loading in chrome. Showing only Loading

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have an asp.net application where i have added ssrs report by using asp.net report viewer but few reports are showing only loading for long time in chrome but if i open that application in Internet explorer then all reports works fine.

May you suggest the problem. Is there any plugin which i need to add in chrome..

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in

Comment: Hi Raritosh, This is not working. I have tried whatever is suggested in this... do you have any other idea ?