# SSRS Report with Matrix could not freeze Row Header in Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, matrix, reporting-services, freeze, rowheader

I am rendering a SSRS report using report viewer in asp .net page and SQL Server 2008 R2.

In a report I have used Matrix control to show data. I have freeze the Row Header of Matrix using `FixedRowHeaders`. It work perfectly fine in Firefox and IE Browsers.

**Problem is in Chrome browser.**

First of all Report was not displayed in Chrome browser. So after so much googling I find a solution for that from a StackOverFlow post ([SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports in Safari/Chrome but works fine in Firefox/Internet Explorer 8... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in))

So as per solution `overflow:auto` property should be set as `overflow:visible` for a div of report and now it is displaying completely.

But, here my Freezing of Row Headers is wipe out. Row Headers are not fixing and horizontal browser scroll is enabled and when i scroll horizontally, the reference Row headers are disappear because of scrolling.

Please suggest me a good solution so that I can show report with Fixed Row Header to matrix. And **this issue is only with Chrome browser**.

Answer (score 0):

As per my thinking it is happening because when i am interfering with existing `ReportingService.js` file to get the rid of `overflow:auto` property the `FixedRowHeaders` functionality is break down to work.