# Cannot view SSRS reports in Safari - report rendering issue - why?

Tags: reporting-services, safari, rendering, sql-server-2000, ssrs-2014

When accessing deployed SSRS reports via URL link using AD authenticated username/password, reports do not complete their rendering. The parameter bar displays with appropriate values and the Loading wheel displays until an error is thrown.

About 75% of the time the error shown is:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   has occurred while processing the request on the server. The status
>   code returned from the server was: 500

The rest of the time the status code returned is: 0

As an added curveball, when connected to internal Wifi the reports render accurately and quickly in Safari on Apple devices.

Reports render correctly in IE, Firefox and Chrome. Using Chrome on any Apple device has been shown to work in all tests so far. Unfortunately using any other browser than Safari is not possible in production.

Additional information

Server does receive a successful login in Event Viewer but nothing gets to the Reporting Services ExecutionLog stored procedures.

The rendering times out at around 120 seconds. A timeout issue could be involved but I can not currently find the appropriate setting to change and even if this is the fault, waiting over 2 minutes to reports this small is inappropriate.

Environment

- SQL Server Reporting Services 2014
- Accessing data from SQL Server 2000
- Issue occurs in Safari browser on Mac, iPhone, iPad for iOS 9.1 and 9.2 (other OSs not tested)
- When working reports show a variety of data from multiple databases on a single SQL server. They access several stored procedures to display parameter dropdowns and general report data organised in tables and graphs with images

Resolves trialled (and failed :)

- Creating non database linked report with picture and one line of text (still did not render)
- Changing ReportingServices and ReportManager web config file to increase httpRuntime executionTimeout and maxRequestLength values (still did not render)
- Changing to Basic authentication (stopped any connection to any aspect of report manager etc)
- Changes to javascript file (still did not render)

I have scanned the internet and of course here on Stack Overflow to little avail. I may have missed something or interpreted it incorrectly so any assistance, suggestions and help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Safari and Chrome render differently than Internet Explorer.

SSRS reports use the DIV tag with overflow: auto that renders the report invisible in Safari and Chrome.

See this for more info on how to deal with the issue:

[SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports in Safari/Chrome but works fine in Firefox/Internet Explorer 8... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in)

Comment: Thanks for your response Hannover Fist. Unfortunately I have viewed the link already and the suggested fix did not resolve the problem. I believe my issue to be different as viewing with Chrome is no problem and internally the reports are viewable in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I had some SSRS report timeout issues earlier too (tried a few things in your suggestions too and didn't work).  I discovered the rendering process would fail when report result set is too big.  I ended up adding some page break to the report so report can be browsed by page to fix the issue.  Hope this help.

Comment: Cheers Sean - I'll have a play with your suggestion to see if it helps the diagnosis - will report back once I've had a chance to do so