# Reportviewer - doesnt return a report on my pc only

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting, report-viewer2012

This is the first time I am working with Microsoft Reporting Services and ReportViewer v11.0.0.0. There is a project on Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2008 and ReportViewer v11.0.0.0. This project can be run in another computers, but for my computer when I run the project, after inputting the parameters, I receive a blank page (all white), basically reportviewer does not show the report that is seen on another computers.

```
// .net
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" />
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rv" runat="server" AsyncRendering="true" Width="100%" Height="900px" ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowPrintButton="false" onreporterror="rv_ReportError"/>
</form>

// c#
rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
rv.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
rv.ShowRefreshButton = false;

rv.ServerReport.Timeout = 12500000;
rv.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportViewerModel.ReportPath;

rv.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(AppUtil.GetReportExecutionUrl());

rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportViewerModel.ReportParameters);
rv.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

The code is like above, but I don't think there is something we need to do on the code since this is working for another computers. I tried many things like below but couldn't fix:

1. EnablePartialRendering: true (for ScriptManager),
2. AsyncRendering: false,
3. Uninstalling/Installing the reporting services and reportviewer. Trying the previous versions too.
4. Remove and add webforms.dl and winforms.dll again to the project from GAC (windows/assembly/gac_msil)
5. Changing target url while installing reporting services: (localhost/Reportserver is now, it is up and working).

I am stuck right now. I checked all the related questions and tried their solutions one by one but none of them solved it. I do not know what can I else do? What should I check, where do I need to focus?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Edit: There is no error message received at some point.

Comment: I suppose you are running the reports from a web browser right?, if that is the case what browser are you using?

Comment: Both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome did not work.

Comment: Also, operating system is Windows 7 x64. Just in case.

Comment: Are your parameter fields visible but your report area white, or is everything on the screen white

Comment: Everything on the screen white, no fields...

Comment: I had a similar problem, but my fields did show up in the screen, what i used was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in you should try it and see if that could be the problem

Comment: Yep, I checked it a few hours before, didnt solve mine :(

Comment: If it runs OK on everyone else's computers it might be only a problem with your computer or browser, have you tried deleting temp files, cache and checking for running plugins like adblock?

Comment: Yes, removed browser cache, disable all plugins (even antivirus and firewall) etc. didnt help at all:(

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble using the report viewer references in the past as well. I have gotten them to work using a Winforms project, but had issues with aspx. I ended up using simple links and Command Render to open SSRS reports on a few different applications. You may want to try using something like this if you are stuck elsewhere.

```
string reportHref = "http://DbSSRSHost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fUser+Reports" + 
                            "&rs:Command=Render&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate + "&JobNumber=" + jobNum + "&ToDepartment=empty";
```

A string like this one is used in an application along with something like an anchor and Href, System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("url") or any other method you like. You can pass any parameters that you need as well using normal parameter string syntax after the Command=Render.

There might be some configuration that you need to do in order to use you Report server this way, and it might not be the best way to do things, but I figured I could mention it anyhow. This MSDN libary goes over some of the aspects of accessing SSRS reports through url:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx