# ReportViewerForMvc report content is blank

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, reportviewer

i had created a .rdlc with only background image.

when i render the report in mvc view page, the reportviewer have blank content.
But if i download as pdf, excel or word, it have content.

in controller page

```
        ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();
        rv.Height = Unit.Parse("100%");
        rv.Width = Unit.Parse("100%");
        rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath)
            + @"Report\Test.rdlc";


        rv.LocalReport.Refresh();

        ViewBag.ReportViewer = rv;
        return View(RM);
```

in .cshtml page

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
            <button>Generate</button>
            @if (ViewBag.ReportViewer != null)
            {
                @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { @style = "width:100%;height:600px" })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

in .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="ReportViewerForMvc.ReportViewerWebForm" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ReportViewerForMvc" Name="ReportViewerForMvc.Scripts.PostMessage.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" AsyncRendering="false" runat="server"
                 Width="100%" Height="600px"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

output

[image]

Comment: Is this on Chrome? Try it on Internet Explorer.

Comment: yes it is chrome, and yes, in IE it have content!, but why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a fix for this problem [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in).

It seems that the styles and elements are built for use on Internet Explorer.

Comment: the report is too large for the page without scroll bar

Comment: So, no fix from the link I provided worked? It shouldn't be a problem if you have scroll bars.

Comment: with the link, i can show the content, but the content is too width