# SSRS DatePicker Is invisible in Google Chrome - Works fine in Firefox and IE

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014

[image]

I'm working on SSRS Report, It shows datepicker in Firefox browser as well as in IE Browser but not showing in Google Chrome. Can anyone please help me.

**ReportView.aspx**

```
<div id="divReportViewer" runat="server" style="overflow: auto;">
  <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvReports" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" AsyncRendering="true" ShowBackButton="false" ShowExportControls="true" ShowPrintButton="false">
  </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

I don't want to use Jquery Calendar. I want to use SSRS date picker. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot view SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 Reports in Safari/Chrome but works fine in FireFox/IE8... why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/cannot-view-ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine-in)

Comment: no - it's not duplicate, please check my screen shot... it is not showing calendar only... please guide me.

Comment: Not all browsers or versions are supported. You must use a browser that has script support enabled. If the browser cannot run scripts, you cannot view the report.

**Source:**
[Browser Support for ReportViewer Web Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673.aspx)

It's also possible that a layout fix might solve your problem:  
[Gotcha: Reporting Services Viewer bugs on Google Chrome](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/06/28/Gotcha-Reporting-Services-Viewer-bugs-on-Google-Chrome.aspx)

Comment: in blog, it has mentioned neede AsyncEnabled = true, so where I can find this property?

Comment: I believe he meant `AsyncRendering = true`

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into something very similar myself (an SSRS report not working properly in Chrome after it was deployed).

As was the case with you, it worked in IE, so I had resigned myself to being forced to use IE for reports.

That is until I changed versions of SQL from 2008 to 2014, and to my surprise, the report viewer then worked in Chrome.

So I suggest an upgrade (because who wants to use IE?!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am using SSRS 2012 and I can't upgrade to SSRS 2014. Finding some another solution.

Comment: No problem! I'll be curious to hear if you come up with some alternative.