# SSRS Data does not display when run remotely

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Report Server in which I can run the report on the remote server and display correctly. (I apologize for the color scheme. I am troubleshooting)
[image]

When I try to run the same report from my local machine by connecting to the remote server.  The report runs but no data is displayed.  No errors are reported.  I have the Report Server switch set to display errors.
[image]

This report has 2 pages and you can use the arrows without error.  So I think the query is running and returning data.  But there is something wrong with the display that the data is not showing.

On the remote server I use IE.  On my local machine I use Chrome.
I have all of the permissions checked for folder, site and report.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I was able to get the report to display in Chrome by adding the extension "SSRS Report Fix" to Google Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-report-fix/fjbdfjiheheafbioiejbdpalmojkeobk

However, the report will still not display in my angular application when trying to view it.  There are no errors.  The data will not display.

Comment: Use IE instead of Chrome or Firefox

Comment: That is not an option.  I was able to view the report by adding an extension to Chrome called SSRS Report Fix.  However, when I try to display the report within the application, the data is still not displaying

Comment: I have not tested this, but have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reportviewer-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me...
To view the report using Google Chrome I added the extension, **SSRS Reports Fix**.  The link is in my updated post.

This did **NOT** fix the problem when I tried to display the report in an AngularJS application.

To fix this problem, I had to add this:

```
div {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

to the css file, **ReportingServices.css** on my Report Server.
This file was located here on my server:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
>   Services\ReportManager\Styles