# rdlc data not showing in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, reporting-services

Data is not shown in Google Chrome but working in IE and FF .
When I am export data, data is shown in exportable format.
I am also add bellow code.

```
// container is either the ReportViewer control itself, or a div containing it. 

function fixReportingServices(container) {
    if ($.browser.safari) { // toolbars appeared on separate lines. 
        $('#' + container + ' table').each(function (i, item) {
            if ($(item).attr('id') && $(item).attr('id').match(/fixedTable$/) != null)
                $(item).css('display', 'table');
            else
                $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
        });
    }
}

// needed when AsyncEnabled=true. 

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () { fixReportingServices('rpt-container'); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `ZoomMode="PageWidth"` and `SizeToReportContent="True"` attributes to ReportViewer control in Viewer.aspx page.

**Example:**

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" ZoomMode="PageWidth" SizeToReportContent="True"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is not a supported browser for viewing Reporting Services reports. However there are some workarounds available.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome/) has an answer that may be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

ReportViewer needs a height in px.  100% will not work.  I hope this helps someone.