# SSRS in Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services

I cannot get my SSRS reports to show in Chrome or Safari.

I'm using Reporting Services 2012, with Reports Builder 3.

I followed the instructions in this post:
[SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports are blank in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome)

I used `ctl32_ctl09` instead of `ctl32_ctl10`.

The only difference was the location of the js file.
The previous answer said to update the file:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js

I could only find the following file:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js

Here are the last few lines of the file I updated (showing the addition):

```
function ChangeDisabledButtonState(c,b){var a=document.getElementById(c);if(a!=null)a.disabled=b}function IsRadioButtonChecked(b){var a=document.getElementById(b);return a!=null&&a.checked?true:false}function pageLoad() {var element = document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl09");if(element){element.style.overflow = "visible";}};
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it says at the link you posted... "If this solution doesn't work, look at the HTML from your browser to see if the script has worked properly changing the overflow:auto property to overflow:visible." -- have you done this and what does it show?  there's also more solutions on that page... did you try anything else?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin. You're right. It was still "auto". Afterwards I tried some other answers. The one by Eric Weiss worked! (obviously with the help of a Control F5 ;)  I'd move it up, but don't have a high enough rep...