# SSRS work in vs studio preview but blank page in browser

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i'm new to ssrs, i created AdventureWorksDW2008R2 DB for sql server 2008 R2, and try to create a report for that, here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

After deployed the datasource and report, when i go to http://vm2012/Reports and enter domain user account and password, then i click the report, the report don't not show any employees name.

What is the problem?

Comment: it seems that chrome problem, i can view the report by using IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the chrome `overflow:auto` rendering is different than IE.

You can have more details on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229038/4840746).

The TL;DR is:

Update the file located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<YourSSRSInstance>\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js`

and append the following script:

```
function pageLoad() {    
var element = document.getElementById("<divName>");
if (element) 
{
    element.style.overflow = "visible"; 
} }
```

Replace `<divName>` with the name of the div.

Then the report should be displayed correctly in chrome.