# Table content overlflows beyond page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a HTML page where i am embedding an SSRS report. The report goes beyond the page as seen in the pic below:
[image]

this is the table that is generated:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_fixedTable" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;">
        <tbody><tr style="background-color:White;">
            <td style="display: none; width: 25%;"></td><td style="display: none; width: 6px;"></td><td style="width:100%;"></td>
        </tr><tr id="ParametersRowctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer" style="display:none;">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr><tr style="height:6px;font-size:2pt;display:none;">
            <td colspan="3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;text-align:center;background-color:#ECE9D8;"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ToggleParam">
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ToggleParam$img" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ToggleParam_img" title="Show / Hide Parameters" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterHorizCollapse.png" alt="Show / Hide Parameters" align="middle" onclick="void(0);" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ToggleParam$store" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ToggleParam_store"><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ToggleParam$collapse" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ToggleParam_collapse" value="false">
            </div></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC Solid;background-color:White;background-image:url(/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=BackImage&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Color=White&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png);">
                <div style="padding-left:6px;">
                    <div class=" " style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First">
                                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First_ctl00" style="display: none; border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <table title="First Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$First$ctl00$ctl00" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First_ctl00_ctl00" title="First Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.FirstPage.gif" alt="First Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$First$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First_ctl00_ctl01" title="First Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.LastPage.gif" alt="First Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First_ctl01" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" style="border:1px transparent Solid;">
                                        <table title="First Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$First$ctl01$ctl00" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First_ctl01_ctl00" title="First Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.FirstPageDisabled.gif" alt="First Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;cursor:default;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$First$ctl01$ctl01" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_First_ctl01_ctl01" title="First Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.LastPageDisabled.gif" alt="First Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;cursor:default;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous">
                                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous_ctl00" style="display: none; border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <table title="Previous Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Previous$ctl00$ctl00" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous_ctl00_ctl00" title="Previous Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.PrevPage.gif" alt="Previous Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Previous$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous_ctl00_ctl01" title="Previous Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPage.gif" alt="Previous Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous_ctl01" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" style="border:1px transparent Solid;">
                                        <table title="Previous Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Previous$ctl01$ctl00" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous_ctl01_ctl00" title="Previous Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.PrevPageDisabled.gif" alt="Previous Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;cursor:default;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Previous$ctl01$ctl01" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Previous_ctl01_ctl01" title="Previous Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPageDisabled.gif" alt="Previous Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;cursor:default;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$CurrentPage" type="text" maxlength="8" size="3" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_CurrentPage" title="Current Page" class="aspNetDisabled" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;">of</span></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><span id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_TotalPages" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;white-space:nowrap;">1</span></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next">
                                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next_ctl00" style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; display: none; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <table title="Next Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Next$ctl00$ctl00" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00" title="Next Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPage.gif" alt="Next Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Next$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl01" title="Next Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.PrevPage.gif" alt="Next Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next_ctl01" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" style="border: 1px solid transparent;">
                                        <table title="Next Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Next$ctl01$ctl00" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next_ctl01_ctl00" title="Next Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPageDisabled.gif" alt="Next Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;cursor:default;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Next$ctl01$ctl01" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Next_ctl01_ctl01" title="Next Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.PrevPageDisabled.gif" alt="Next Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;cursor:default;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last">
                                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last_ctl00" style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; display: none; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <table title="Last Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Last$ctl00$ctl00" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last_ctl00_ctl00" title="Last Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.LastPage.gif" alt="Last Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Last$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last_ctl00_ctl01" title="Last Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.FirstPage.gif" alt="Last Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last_ctl01" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" style="border: 1px solid transparent;">
                                        <table title="Last Page">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Last$ctl01$ctl00" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last_ctl01_ctl00" title="Last Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.LastPageDisabled.gif" alt="Last Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;cursor:default;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl00$Last$ctl01$ctl01" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl00_Last_ctl01_ctl01" title="Last Page" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.FirstPageDisabled.gif" alt="Last Page" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;cursor:default;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" toolbarspacer="true" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><div class=" " style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00">
                                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00" style="display: none; border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <table title="Go back to the parent report">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00" title="Go back to the parent report" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.BackEnabled.gif" alt="Go back to the parent report" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl00$ctl01" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl01" title="Go back to the parent report" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.BackRTLEnabled.gif" alt="Go back to the parent report" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl01" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" style="border:1px transparent Solid;">
                                        <table title="Go back to the parent report">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00" title="Go back to the parent report" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.BackDisabled.gif" alt="Go back to the parent report" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;cursor:default;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl01$ctl01" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl01_ctl01" title="Go back to the parent report" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.BackRTLDisabled.gif" alt="Go back to the parent report" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;display:none;cursor:default;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" toolbarspacer="true" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><div class=" " style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="28px"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00" type="text" maxlength="255" size="10" id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00" title="Find Text in Report" class="aspNetDisabled" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><a id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl03_ctl01" title="Find" href="#" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; color: gray; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; cursor: default;">Find</a></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;">|</span></td><td width="4px"></td><td height="28px"><a id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl03_ctl03" title="Find Next" href="#" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; color: gray; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; cursor: default;">Next</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" toolbarspacer="true" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><div class=" " style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                    <table id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button" title="Export drop down menu">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td><a id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonLink" title="Export drop down menu" alt="Export drop down menu" href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;"><img id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImg" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.Export.gif" alt="Export drop down menu" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"><span style="width:5px;text-decoration:none;"> </span><img id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImgDown" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.ArrowDown.gif" alt="Export drop down menu" style="border-style:None;height:6px;width:7px;margin-bottom:5px;"></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu" style="background-color:White;border:1px #336699 Solid;display:none;position:absolute;padding:1px;z-index:1;">
                                    <div style="border: 1px solid rgb(51, 102, 153); cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(221, 238, 247);">
                                        <a title="XML file with report data" alt="XML file with report data" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('XML');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">XML file with report data</a>
                                    </div><div style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <a title="CSV (comma delimited)" alt="CSV (comma delimited)" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('CSV');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">CSV (comma delimited)</a>
                                    </div><div style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <a title="PDF" alt="PDF" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('PDF');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">PDF</a>
                                    </div><div style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <a title="MHTML (web archive)" alt="MHTML (web archive)" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('MHTML');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">MHTML (web archive)</a>
                                    </div><div style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <a title="Excel" alt="Excel" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">Excel</a>
                                    </div><div style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <a title="TIFF file" alt="TIFF file" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('IMAGE');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">TIFF file</a>
                                    </div><div style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <a title="Word" alt="Word" onclick="$find('ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer').exportReport('WORDOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none;">Word</a>
                                    </div>
                                <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 26px; opacity: 0.05; background-color: black;"></div></div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" toolbarspacer="true" style="display:inline-block;width:6px;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table><div class=" " style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="28px"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00">
                                    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00" style="border: 1px solid transparent; cursor: default; background-color: transparent;">
                                        <table title="Refresh">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl05$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00" title="Refresh" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.Refresh.gif" alt="Refresh" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
                                    </div><div id="ctl00_MainContent_FiveYearReportViewer_ctl05_ctl05_ctl00_ctl01" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" style="border: 1px solid transparent; display: none;">
                                        <table title="Refresh">
                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                <td><input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$FiveYearReportViewer$ctl05$ctl05$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00" disabled="disabled" title="Refresh" src="/BlockGrantV2WebSite/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.3452.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.RefreshDisabled.gif" alt="Refresh" style="border-style:None;height:16px;width:16px;cursor:default;"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody></table>
```

How to correct this so that the page header also grows in size when the table is expanded? Is there any css property that i can set either initially or call it after the pageload via javascript?

Comment: Holy crud this is some messy code. Inline styles? Gasp! Code that has been copy and pasted which is missing tons of closing tags? The horror! If your code is really missing the closing tags that will cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: Based on the code you provided I dont even come close to duplicating the screen shot you provided. So I suggest if you want people to help you will add more of your code

Comment: Well i crossed the character limit on the question and ended up deleting quite a few lines at the end of the code. 
Also the table is generated via SSRS so i am not sure how you would be able to duplicate the screenshot :(

Comment: If thats the case I suggest recreating the issue in Codeply or JS.Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was being caused due to me using the workaround from another SSRS problem:
[SSRS 2008 R2 - SSRS 2012 - ReportViewer: Reports are blank in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome)

Changing the property to `element.style.overflow = "scroll";` solved it for me.