# How can I get SSRS and Chrome to work together?

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, cross-browser, reportbuilder, rdl

Chrome is my preferred browser; I need to interact with SQL Server Reporting Services, though, and when I navigate to a report created with Report Builder (*.rdl file), in Chrome I get no contextual menu. When hovering over the report, it does "light up" (a yellow border is drawn around it) and a dropdown arrow appears in the NE corner, but clicking it does nothing whatsoever.

In IE, it works just fine. However, I really don't want to use IE if I don't have to.

Sharepoint has similar issues (things that can't be done in Chrome and Firefox work fine in IE). Do I just have to "bite the bullet" and use IE when interfacing with Microsoft products, or is there a way to use SSRS from Chrome?

Comment: Have you seen the following workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome ?  I should also mention that with the upcoming SS2016 this nagging issue is supposed to resolved finally, with HTML5 support for SSRS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2015/09/02/what-s-new-in-reporting-services-in-sql-server-2016-ctp-2-3.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to this very much depends on the version of SQL Server Reporting Services being used, which you haven't mentioned.

In the upcoming [SQL Server 2016 version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.130).aspx), Chrome is a fully supported browser for interacting with Reporting Services.

However for earlier versions, the only non-IE browsers supported (or at least partially supported) are Firefox and Safari. Older versions support progressively fewer features for non-IE browsers.

This means unless you have SQL Server 2016, using Chrome for reporting services is going to mean compatibility issues. To work around this there are a couple of possible solutions:

1) In a corporate environment, consider using the [Legacy Browser Support extensio](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en)n for Chrome - this requires Group Policy settings to force some URLs to open in an IE window.

2) Use the [IE Tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) in Chrome to render certain sites using the IE rendering engine, but inside a Chrome tab.

Comment: FYI: IE Tab is also available in the corporate environment.  Unlike the clunky legacy browser support, IE Tab is seamless and they have Group Policy support.  The ietab.net home page shows a list of high-profile corporate customers and they actually provide support, unlike Google.