# SSRS 2017 Scaleout adding/editing Data Source issue in Chrome

Tags: reporting-services, kerberos, ssrs-2017

I have setup SSRS 2017 Scaleout environment with two nodes and a load balancer. Users can login fine with both IE and Chrome but editing Data Sources works in IE but not in Chrome. Details below.

Here are the high level Installation/Configuration steps.
lets say Nodes are N1, N2. Load balancer vip/name is reports.root3i.com

**Kerberos**

- Created AD user domain\ssrs_svc
- setspn for ssrs_svc with

  - http/N1.root3i.com
  - http/N2.root3i.com
  - http/N1, http/N2
  - http/reports.root3i.com
  - http/reports
- Enabled Kerberos delegation for N1, N2 and ssrs_svc accounts to trust any service

**Install and Setup**

- Setup SSRS on N1 with domain\ssrs_svc
- Created new Report Database on a remote server
- Defaults for Web Service/Report manager url. No Https
- Backed up Encryption Key
- Setup SSRS on N2 with domain\ssrs_svc
- Defaults for Web Service/Report manager url. No Https
- Used existing database on a remote server
- Restored encryption key from N1
- At this time, N1, N2 were already present in the scale-out tab.

**RsReportServer.config**

- Added same machinekey for N1 and N2 with AES Decryption and HMACSHA256 validation.
- Set UrlRoot https://reports.root3i.com
- Hostname to reports.root3i.com
- AuthenticationTypes

---

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
   <RSWindowsKerberos/>
   <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
```

**Permissions**

- Created an AD Group SSRS_Admins
- Assigned System Administrator and User role to the above group under Site Settings -> Security
- Assigned all the roles for Folder level permissions(Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder

**Issue**

Editing Data Sources works fine in IE from a Workstation for users that are member of SSRS_Admins group but using Chrome, we get this generic error "Error has occurred"
RSPortal logs has this error. **"ERROR: OData exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized"**

Is this known issue with Chrome? Did I miss any steps in Config? We would really like it to work on Chrome.

Versions:
Workstation Windows 10 1803
Chrome 68
**Helpful Links:**

https://www.sqlshack.com/scaling-out-reporting-services-changes-in-sql-server-2016/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-report-server-on-a-network-load-balancing-cluster?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: A few years ago I had a similar issue with Chrome not remembering active directory authentication. I've always tried to steer clear of chrome at work for that sort of thing,

This may be useful, I try to argue against using anything other than IE for SSRS portals...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276929/how-can-i-get-ssrs-and-chrome-to-work-together

Comment: MS claims that 2017 SSRS has better browser support. 
"A new HTML5 rendering engine that targets modern web "full" standards mode and modern browsers. The new rendering engine no longer relies on quirks mode used by a few older browsers"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/what-s-new-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017