# SSRS: reports blank in Chrome, but work on Firefox/IE

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

A strange behavior: if a try to open my reports on the SSRS from a Chrome browser I have a blank page (it just appears the upper bar with the reports' field) while if opening the same using Firefox or Internet Explorer, rendering is performed fine.

I retrieved following solution to append following code:

```
function pageLoad() {    
    var element = document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl10");
    if (element) 
    {
        element.style.overflow = "visible"; 
    }
}
```

on the **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js** file.
I tried to put both `ctl31_ctl10` or `ctl31_ctl09` as suggested, all the time also stopping and restarting SSRS services and re-opening chrome browser, but still having this issue.

**SSRS version: 11.0.5058.0
SQL Server 2012**

Does anybody know a solution for that?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed appending to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js\ReportingServices.js**:

```
function initJQuery() {

    //if the jQuery object isn't available
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {


        if (! jQueryScriptOutputted) {
            //only output the script once..
            jQueryScriptOutputted = true;

            //output the script 
            document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../js/jquery-1.6.2.js\"></scr" + "ipt>");
         }
        setTimeout("initJQuery()", 50);
    } else {

        $(function() {     

        // Bug-fix on Chrome and Safari etc (webkit)
        if ($.browser.webkit) {

            // Start timer to make sure overflow is set to visible
             setInterval(function () {
                var div = $('table[id*=_fixedTable] > tbody > tr:last > td:last > div')

                div.css('overflow', 'visible');
            }, 1000);
        }

        });
    }        
}

initJQuery();
```

This also requires to download jquery-1.6.2.js on the same folder as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12501264/5449321