# ssrs 2016 data missing in report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I just recently decided to upgrade from sql 2008 r2 to sq2016 reporting service. I changed the target verion number in vs2015 to match that of the report server and published my reports.

When I run the report it looks like this in edge. I tested in Chrome and get the same result

[image]

This is what it looks like in edge on the old version SSRS
[image]

So some reason it does not work properly on the 2016 but if I open the report using the report builder via 2016 and run the report in there it is fine.

thank you

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reportviewer-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome

Comment: thanks but none of those apply to ssrs 2016