# SSRS2012 not working in Chrome but work in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have set up SSRS2012 Reporting (which obviously works in IE11.0.96). When I try to open the the URL in chrome (49.0.26 - Company SOE)
[http://[Domain Name]/[Virtual Folder]/Pages/Folder.aspx](http://[Domain%20Name]/[Virtual%20Folder]/Pages/Folder.aspx)
I cannot see anything on the page i.e. it's a blank page. I enabled Developer Tools and it reports that it cannot find favicon.ico file. I have placed that file in all SSRS folders, and there is still nothing happening. I have just downloaded Firefox (54.0) and tried the abovementioned URL and it works. So obviously its not the div issue or css issue spoken about in other forum replies.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Already asked and answered I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968082/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reportviewer-reports-are-blank-in-safari-and-chrome

Comment: This forum post talk about that Report is not being Rendered properly, and through developer tools you can find out the offending <div> and add a hack in it. But in my case, nothing is being rendered. I am checking via developer tools and I am getting an error about "favicon.ico" file and nothing else comes up in developer tools. I have also said that the Reports are working find in FireFox.

Comment: I have an issue where reports render fine in ie and Firefox but blank in chrome. I fail to see how a favicon error can be related. Reports being blank in chrome is a well known and highly documented issue with many fixes out there. I have provided you with the fix that worked for me.