# Multiple window.onload function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have JavaScript functions called `start()` that have multiple functions to load using `window.onload` function. However, I have below function that works independently fine. However, if I write it inside the `window.onload`, then it doesn't work.

```
//START()     
window.onload = start;

function start()
{
    loadValues();
    showState4();
}
```

Code that does work independently fine.

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("src2TargetAll").onclick = function() {
        sureTransfer(document.getElementById("net"), document.getElementById("target"), true);
    };
};
```

I tried re-writing the code as follows in `window.onload` but it doesn't work. How to re-write the below code in single `window.onload` function.

```
window.onload = start;

function start()
{
    loadValues();  //loadValues() and showState4() works fine without sendValues().
    showState4();
    sendValuess();  // tested this sendValues without above two functions and that also works fine. but three functions in window.onload creates a problem
}


function sendValuess(){
    document.getElementById("src2TargetAll").onclick = function() {
        sureTransfer(document.getElementById("net"), document.getElementById("target"), true);
    };
};
```

Error that I get after adding `sendValues()` to `window.onload` is as follows:

> STOP RUNNING THIS SCRIPT?
> A SCRIPT ON THIS PAGE IS CAUSING YOUR WEB BROWSER TO RUN SLOWLY. IF IT CONTINUES TO RUN, YOUR COMPUTER MIGHT BECOME UNRESPONSIVE.

Below is the code for `loadValues` and other functions as requested by a person who trying to help me:

```
function showState4(){
        var me = document.getElementById('stk1');
         var values = ''; //populate selected options
         for (var i=0; i<me.length; i++)
             if (me.options[i].selected)
                 values += me.options[i].value + ',';
         values = values.substring(0, values.length-1);
         var selected=[values];
         
         var temp= new Array();
            temp = values.split(",");
         
         var del = document.getElementById('StakeHolder');
          
         for(var i=0; i<del.length; i++)
           {
             for(var j=0;j<temp.length;j++)
              {  
                   
                  if(temp[j] == del.options[i].value)
                    {
                         
                       del.options[i].selected = true;
                    }
               }  
           }
         }

     function loadValues()
     {
    var  RD_REQ_RT_ID = "<%=RD_REQ_RT_ID %>";
    if(RD_REQ_RT_ID=="null")
     {
    document.getElementById('requestType').value="";
     }
     else{
    document.getElementById('requestType').value=RD_REQ_RT_ID;
    }
    )


_

     function sureTransfer(from, to, all) {
    if ( from.getElementsByTagName && to.appendChild ) {
        while ( getCount(from, !all) > 0 ) {
            transfer(from, to, all);
        }
    }
     }
     function getCount(target, isSelected) {
    var options = target.getElementsByTagName("option");
    if ( !isSelected ) {
        return options.length;
    }
    var count = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( isSelected && options[i].selected ) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
    }
    function transfer(from, to, all) {
    if ( from.getElementsByTagName && to.appendChild ) {
        var options = from.getElementsByTagName("option");
        for ( i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
            if ( all ) {
                to.appendChild(options[i]);
            } else {
                if ( options[i].selected ) {
                    to.appendChild(options[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
     }
```

How to add `sendValuess()` to `window.onload` without any issue?

Comment: Share your code for `loadValues`, `showState4` and `sureTransfer`.

Comment: Is it OK for you to use jQuery?

Comment: i think this post can help you :) 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434/how-do-i-add-an-additional-window-onload-event-in-javascript

Comment: Marawan, I already did that. the issue is only while adding the third one. First two works fine without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

`window.addEventListener` will not work in IE so use `window.attachEvent`.

You can do something like this:

```
function fun1(){
    // do something
}

function fun2(){
    // do something
}


var addFunctionOnWindowLoad = function(callback){
      if(window.addEventListener){
          window.addEventListener('load',callback,false);
      }else{
          window.attachEvent('onload',callback);
      }
}

addFunctionOnWindowLoad(fun1);
addFunctionOnWindowLoad(fun2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
STOP RUNNING THIS SCRIPT?
A SCRIPT ON THIS PAGE IS CAUSING YOUR WEB BROWSER TO RUN SLOWLY.
IF IT CONTINUES TO RUN, YOUR COMPUTER MIGHT BECOME UNRESPONSIVE.
```

It occures when IE is running in compatibility mode. (happens while using FB and Google+)
goto "Tools" menu and select the "Compatibility View Settings" option. This will open a window where you can turn off the feature "Display all websites using Compatibility View".

Comment: what is the error you are getting?
check console. in mozilla ctrl+shift+j

Comment: @ Mayank: no error at console. The error that I get as pop-up is as below:   STOP RUNNING THIS SCRIPT?
A SCRIPT ON THIS PAGE IS CAUSING YOUR WEB BROWSER TO RUN SLOWLY. IF IT CONTINUES TO RUN, YOUR COMPUTER MIGHT BECOME UNRESPONSIVE.

Comment: It seems that you are using "internet exploder"...try some other browser