# How is it possible to set more window.onload events?

Tags: javascript

I have three functions, which I would like to call, when the page is loaded. I tried this:

```
window.onload = [function f1(){...}, function f2(){...}, function f3(){...}];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have no idea how should I manage it.

Comment: try `addEventListener` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/688199/896341

Comment: I think `addEventListener` is overkill for this requirement, and not ideal because of browser compatibility issues.  Besides, it's easy to roll a function chaining mechanism in a closure-capable language like JavaScript.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set multiple event handlers, it's not supported.  If you need to execute multiple functions, then you just have to call them sequentially one after another:

```
function f1() { ... }
function f2() { ... }
function f3() { ... }

window.onload = function() {
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
}
```

Most of javascript libraries provide you with ways to add multiple function calls to the event handler - and will do the chaining for you.  For example, with jQuery you can do this:

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
$(window).load(function() { ... });
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

This will *not* override the previous invocation with the new one, but will set all three to be called from the `onload` event.

**UPDATE:** another way of dealing with it would be to use `addEventListener` on your `window` object.

```
function f1() { ... }
function f2() { ... }
function f3() { ... }

window.addEventListener("load", f1);
window.addEventListener("load", f2);
window.addEventListener("load", f3);
```

or even

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { ... });
window.addEventListener("load", function() { ... });
window.addEventListener("load", function() { ... });
```

These two code snippets are equivalent to the first one - and with each other.

Comment: @Teemu agreee.  I updated my answer to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Under the category of obfuscated code, here's an option to consider as brain exercise:

```
window.onload = function() {
  return this.forEach(Function.prototype.call, Function.prototype.call);
}.bind([function f1(){...}, function f2(){...}, function f3(){...}]);
```

It will work on browsers that implement `Array.forEach()` and `Function.prototype.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap all the functions in a anonymous function

```
window.onload = function(){
  f1();
  f2();
  f3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your functions before calling them from one function:

```
window.onload = function () {
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
}
```

With [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) you can define more than one listener for `onload`. Listeners are executed in the order of definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to add them dynamically:

```
function addWindowOnload(next) {
    var prev = window.onload; 
    window.onload = function() {
        if (prev) prev();
        next();
    };
}
```