# Add another event at runtime

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Save" onclick="return validate(event, document.thisForm)"></a>
```

and I would like to add at runtime by JS something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Save" onclick="return validate(event, document.thisForm) && submitForm(document.thisForm)"></a>
```

My idea was doing like this but I dont know how to add AND operator:

```
form.addEventListener('submitForm', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('onclick handler called');
}, false);
```

Comment: you call call two functions like `a(); b();` next to each other

Comment: @Kaushik I need call them with AND operator and with return.

Comment: You can try something analog to what is shown here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814/10955263 This stores the reference to the existing event handler function first (which can be one created implicitly by `onclick="..."`), and then overwrites the event handler with an new one, that calls the _old_ one, and additionally does its own thing.

Comment: @04FS Looks like good solution but still I need AND operator due return of event.

Comment: Well then put it between the two function calls that are made there ... `old(); fn();` -> `old() && fn()`

Comment: @04FS Yes simple answer but when I will put more different calls?

Comment: If you have to add a third function and still join everything with AND, then repeat the same process a second time? `A && B && C == (A && B) && C`, after all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To not change the HTML itself you can do this

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  let saveBut = document.querySelector('a[title="Save"]');
  let form = document.querySelector("[name=thisForm]");
  form.addEventListener("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }); // stop submission by other means than the link
  saveBut.onclick=null; // remove the inline event handler
  saveBut.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link's click 
    if (validate(e, form)) submitForm(form); // call submitForm if valid
  });
});
```

Comment: Exists code generated on server side must be untouched. Soo thats why I am looking for solution to add another call by JS.

Comment: You can easily replace the link with a submit button from script

Comment: Sorry but its not soo smart solution. All is hardcoded.

Comment: @step Very unhelpful comment. In what way not smart? You set the limitations

Comment: @step All what is hardcoded? I only have your code to look at - all the information about link and form name is from what you tell me

Answer (score -1):

1. 'submitForm' is referenced as a function in your onclick attribute, but you're trying to use it as an event. It won't work like that, `<form>` doesn't emit an event called 'submitForm', and it's not being called when you call a submitForm function. `<form>` does have a `submit` event.
2. You should avoid using the `onclick` attribute (and other on* attributes). Use IDs and addEventHandler to add a `click` event handler. Then you can just write an entire multi-line function in that handler.
3. You can also use an `<input>` or `<button>` of `type=submit` and then add an event listener of type `submit` to the form (if your form is a `<form>` element). Then you will not need to call any other functions from event listeners. The form will handle that.